# PySide - QFormLayout - alignment problems

Tags: python, pyside

I'm trying to use QFromLayout for a PySide panel, but I can't get alignment to work. I would like to have all fields line up vertically. Currently they are not lining up, I guess becuse of the length of the label? I tried with bot setHorizontalAlignment() and to fill the label with white spaces, but no luck.

---

Edit:

[Here's a better example of what's not aligned.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiHl8.jpg)

Basically I want all "column 2" to be aligned vertically.

---

Any ideas? [Image of panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gTmZ.png)

```
import sys
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *

class MyPanel(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MyPanel, self).__init__(parent)

        self.grp1 = QGroupBox()
        self.form_layout1 = QFormLayout()

        self.drop1 = QComboBox()
        self.drop1.addItems(["item1", "item2"])
        self.form_layout1.addRow('drop', self.drop1)

        self.line1 = QLineEdit()
        self.form_layout1.addRow("long long line", self.line1)

        self.btn1 = QPushButton("button")
        self.form_layout1.addRow("", self.btn1)

        self.grp2 = QGroupBox()
        self.form_layout2 = QFormLayout()

        self.check2 = QCheckBox()
        self.form_layout2.addRow("checkbox", self.check2)

        self.line2 = QLineEdit()
        self.form_layout2.addRow("line", self.line2)

        # Set layouts.
        self.grp1.setLayout(self.form_layout1)
        self.grp2.setLayout(self.form_layout2)

        # Main layout.
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.layout.addWidget(self.grp1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.grp2)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)

# Show
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
panel = MyPanel()
panel.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Do you mean it's not aligned inside each of the two form layouts, or that the two forms are not aligned together ?

Comment: Hi tmoreau! Basically one can describe a form layout as a row with two columns (1 and 2). Basically I would like all columns 2 in the panel to be aligned vertically. Currently it seems that they are positioned based of the length of the text in column 1 (maybe?). I will update the original post with another image. Thanks!

Comment: The issue is that you have two form_layout. Inside each group, all is aligned, but between the two groups it is not aligned. That is the normal behaviour: if you want everything to be aligned, you have to use only one `QFormLayout`. Otherwise look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985785/make-qformlayouts-inside-multiple-qgroupboxes-have-the-same-column-widths

Comment: Thanks! It seems lika a QGridLayout is better suited for this as I can specify the width of columns much easier. Cheers!